# How to use PDFThumbnailView in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

I am trying use PDFThumbnailView in PDFKit to display thumbnails of a pdf document but I cannot get it to work.  There are no errors showing in the console.  I just get a blank viewController. Below is my code.  Please can someone advise on where i am going wrong?

I have dragged an UIView object and assigned it the following class 'PDFThumbnailView'.

[image]

```
 import UIKit
 import PDFKit

 class pdfThumbNailViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var myThumbNailView: PDFThumbnailView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // create PDFView Object
    // Then assign this object as the variable of thumbnailview object
    let myPDFViewObject = PDFView.init()
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "paper", ofType: "pdf"){
        let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path)
        if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument.init(url: url){
            myPDFViewObject.document = pdfDocument

        }
    }
    // Setting thumbnail size
    let size = CGSize.init(width: 50, height: 50)
    myThumbNailView.thumbnailSize = size
    myThumbNailView.layoutMode = .vertical
    myThumbNailView.pdfView = myPDFViewObject

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a blank ViewController because you aren't using your `myThumbnailView` at all..

In `viewDidLoad`, you created a thumbnail view and assigned data to it, but you never actually use your `IBOutlet myThumbNailView`.. therefore it is blank and the local one gets deallocated when `viewDidLoad` finished.

TLDR: `thumbNailObject != myThumbNailView`.. You're using the wrong object reference.

Comment: I have corrected my code to your suggestion but I am still getting a blank viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - in your current code you have a memory problem, that's why you dont see anything in the end:

You have defined your `let myPDFViewObject: PDFView` inside of your `viewDidLoad()` which then lives only in that methods block; as soon as the end of the method is reached your `PDFView` gets deallocated, and in turn the `PDFThumbnailView` has no associated `PDFView` anymore.

You can resolve your problem by just moving `let myPDFViewObject: PDFView` above and outside of your `viewDidLoad()`, which ensures the `PDFView` is going to live longer

Happy coding!

```
let myPDFViewObject = PDFView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Then assign this object as the variable of thumbnailview object
    if let path = Bundle...
```